# I cannot draw a circle in love2d

Tags: lua, rectangles, love2d

I am creating a pong game in love2d and lua where you play against an AI, but i can't get rectangles and circles to draw on the screen, i have tried alot, and looked on other project
that i made but i couldn't find what is the problem, i started programming in love2d
and lua a few months ago so i am not that good, so i am probably missing something
obvious, can someone tell me what it is?

**Main.lua**

```
push = require "Helpers/push"
Class = require "Helpers/class"
require "Objects/AI"
require "Objects/Ball"
require "Objects/Paddle"

dimWidth = 960
dimHeight = 540

resWidth = 480
resHeight = 270

love.window.setTitle("Pong with artificial intelligence")

function love.load()
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")

    Font = love.graphics.newFont("Font/font.ttf")
    love.graphics.setFont(Font)

    push:setupScreen(resWidth, resHeight, dimWidth, dimHeight, {
        fullscreen = false,
        resizable = false,
        vsync = true
    })

    Ball:init()
end
function love.update(dt)

end
function love.keypressed(key)

end
function love.draw()
    push:start()
    
    Ball:render()
    push:finish()
end
```

**Ball.lua**

```
Ball = Class{}

function Ball:init()
    self.x = 800
    self.y = 450
    self.width = 8
    self.height = 8
end

function Ball:update(dt)
end

function Ball:render()
    love.graphics.circle("fill", self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end
```

Comment: The correct parameters are: `love.graphics.circle( mode, x, y, radius )`  A circle does not have width and height.

Comment: @ESkri of course a circle has height and width. it is called diameter.

Comment: No it does not, the [fifth parameter](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.circle) for circle is used for the amount of segments. An Ellipse has two diameters: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.ellipse

Comment: I have another project in love2d where i used width and height on the circle and it worked well

Answer (score 1):

You define a screen with a resolution of 480 x 270, so a circle at (800;450) would be way outside the screen.